# MySQL normalization issue with performance

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table of shops and anoher table of shop configs (plan, discounts and Others configs), I need to add some Fields to store SMTP configs.

Should I create 5 Fields (host,Port,user,pass,ssl) or create 1 field and store a JSON with these informations?

Comment: What do you plan on doing with the JSON data?  Will it be queried and updated often, or only occasionally?

Comment: Occassionally update only, not where or order by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those fields need to be used for searching/filtering (where clause) or for sorting/grouping (order by/group by), then make individual fields for them. If not, saving as JSON encoded or comma delimited will work fine. If the data content lengths are fairly constant for each field, you may save some space by defining individual fields, but unless you have a lot (millions?) of records, disk space is cheap....